# Which font style is this M?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, math-fonts

Does anyone know which font style is this M in the picture?

[image]

It looks like to be  \mathcal{} but without italic. If anyone knows the command to get this font style in the math mode, please tell me. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This is Euler script.  For instructions, `texdoc euscript`.

Comment: This is covered in the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](//texdoc.net/pkg/comprehensive) in Table 307 Math Alphabets. Specifically, load `\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}` and then you can use `$\mathcal{M}~\mathscr{M}$` ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBMTc.png)).

Comment: The problem with the Comprehensive Symbol List is that only the first few letters of an alphabet are shown, and the shapes of the rest of the letters are not always intuitive.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I agree. For what it's worth, I'll send Scott an email and suggest including the entire alphabet for each font. Why not.

Comment: @Werner, Actually, the alphabets are complete in the "raw fonts" that are included in the package, but that isn't documented in the section on alphabets (unless it has been added recently).  That might be a reasonable approach.  Big changes to the document are a real problem.  (I've corresponded with Scott on similar things.)